# Show hierarchical clusters on openstreetmap in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, awt, openstreetmap, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to visualize millions of data (geolocations) as cluster (continuous clustering) on openstreetmap. It's a JAVA Desktop application. I found several libraries (ex: [Animated cluster](http://www.acuriousanimal.com/AnimatedCluster/)) for web based application in javascript. Unfortunately I didn't find any suitable library to implement that knid of hierarchial clustering visualization for java desktop application. A demo link is [here](https://adammertel.github.io/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.PlacementStrategies/demo/demo1.html)

I am looking for proper suggestions to visualize data as clusters for java desktop application like the demo.

Comment: I fear that's way too broad to find any meaningful answer here.

Comment: @Ben In other word I can say, **show clusters on map in JavaFx** . You can check the demo for more detail.

Comment: [Tool/library/project recommendation questions are off topic on this site.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the JavaFX WebView and load openlayers inside. MapFX does it: https://github.com/sothawo/mapjfx